# Wpf Animate label text movement

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

I have a statusbar with three labels in it.  At times the labels have to much text to fit on screen.  I'd like the text of the individual labels to scroll when you mouse over them.

How would I set up the animation for this?

I can use any uneditable control that presents text instead of a label.

Comment: Just bind the tooltip to the text so it displays on hover.

Comment: Any control can be uneditable if you change IsEnabled. Some controls have IsEditable property as well.

Comment: @Will Thanks. I talked to my team and they said tooltips are standard.